# Why doesn't my transition work the first time jquery/css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to make my bootstrap navbar smaller at a certain scroll point. I want it go smoothly so I used `transition: 0.5s;`. It doesn't go smooth at the first time of scrolling down, but when I do it again it goes smoothly. Can someone help me with this?
Here is my jcode

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scrollHeigth = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scrollHeigth === 0) {
 $(".navbar").css({
    'height':'100px',
    'transition':' 0.5s'
});
$('.navbar-logo').css({
    'width':'143px',
    'top' : '10px'
});
} else {
 $(".navbar").css({
   'height':'50px',
});
$('.navbar-logo').css({
   'width':'80px',
   'top' : '3px',
   'transition':' 0.5s'
  });
 }
});
```

Edit:
The `navbar-logo` does go smoothly on the first time of scrolling, the `navbar` doesn't

Comment: Side note, you should avoid doing dom lookups inside a handler such as on scroll, which fires a TON of times.  You should also try to find a resource on throttling or debouncing and see if that could be helpful for you as well.

Comment: ah okay, any suggestion for better code?

Comment: Just put it in an IIFE, do the lookups outside the handler, store them in variables, and use them in the handler, so your only looking up once.

Answer (score 2):

Define the `transition` in your style sheet rather than script. Its causing the problem.

Try in your `<style>`

```
.navbar{
    transition: all ease 0.5s;
 }
```

Comment: Ah I see that works better, I also found out that I did not give the navbar a certain height in my css, thats why it didn't work at the first scroll.

Comment: Glad you find it out by yourself :) anyway see this demo for any reference http://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the transition here also..  So that transition works for both actions

```
$('.navbar-logo').css({
    'width':'143px',
    'top' : '10px'
    'transition':' 0.5s'
});
```

Comment: I edited the question above, the logo is not the problem.